# How to Validate text boxes sequentially in asp.net c#

Tags: c#-3.0

I have 10 textboxes i want to check if user inserts text in 8th textbox it should generate error because he should first fill 7th textbox and so on it can be done using if else but i need it to be done using loops to reduce code

Comment: Thank you for helping me. I did it by checking all the boxes are empty using OR || operator and it worked for me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you planning to fill out the form sequentially??

if you are planning to check as a whole compare each text box name to "null" at time of the click on button

correct me if my view is different from yours

Answer (score 0):

Add attributes to all text boxes like 'data-textbox'. Then you can write the below code to identify which either a text box is empty.

```
$('[data-textbox]').each(function(index, value){
// YOUR CODE TO VALIDATE IT AS EMPTY OR NOT
});
```